# What is the idiomatic way to convert a String to &str?

Tags: string, rust

I've found a number of ways to convert `String` to `&str`. Which one is correct/idiomatic today?

```
let string = "hello".to_string();

let string_slice1 = &string[..];
let string_slice2: &str = &string;
let string_slice3 = &*string;
```

How would I make the second method work without specifying type in variable declaration? Something like `&string as &str` (but it doesn't work). I see that `&string` has `&String` type but when it is implicitly cast to `&str`, it will perform implicit conversion. How do I make that conversion explicit?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are two important things here that `String` implements:

- `Index<RangeFull, Output = str>`: this makes `string[..]` be of type `str`, though you need to take a reference to it (either by calling a method, allowing autoref to happen, or explicitly as `&string[..]`). This explains the `string_slice1`.
- `Deref<Target = str>`: this makes `*string` be of type `str`, with the same considerations on unsized types as in indexing. This is why `string_slice3` works and in a bit of hidden behaviour why `string_slice2` works.

Unlike in C++, `&` is not a pure reference operator: it also allows dereferencing to take place first. `&string` will therefore normally be of type `&String`, but it is possible for it to be of type `&str` if necessary also. If, for example, you were to pass it to a method that took a `&str`, it would work, or if you try to bind it to a variable of type `&str`. This is why the `: &str` is necessary for this case.

General consensus is that type ascription is to be avoided where feasible, so the second form is not desirable. Between the first and third, there is no consensus as to which is more desirable yet.

There's also [`String::as_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_str), which some prefer:

```
let string_slice4 = string.as_str();
```

Comment: However, the second form is nice if it doesn't need a type ascription, i.e., in contexts where the `&str` can be inferred, such as when passing arguments to non-generic functions.

Comment: "... `&` is not a pure reference operator: it also allows dereferencing to take place first." 

Do you mean in the second case, it's really `let string_slice2: &str = &(*string);`