# BadFormat parsing string to date when using Chrono

Tags: datetime, rust

I am trying to convert a string to a date using the Chrono library. I always get a `BadFormat` or `NotEnough` error:

```
extern crate chrono;

use chrono::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let dt1 = DateTime::parse_from_str(
        "2017-08-30 18:34:06.638997932 UTC", 
        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%9f"
    );
    println!("{:?}", dt1);
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: the format string is missing the time zone specifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As mentioned in the comments, your format string doesn't allow for the `" UTC"` part of your string. That's why you get the `BadFormat` error.
2. If you add `" UTC"` to your format string, you still get a `BadFormat` error because you've typed `.%9f` when it should be `%.9f`.
3. Once you fix that, you get a `NotEnough` error because we aren't actually parsing a timezone.

I'd use `NaiveDateTime` to always parse in UTC and then add the `" UTC"` onto the format string to ignore it, correcting the typo:

```
use chrono::prelude::*; // 0.4.9

fn main() {
    let dt1 = NaiveDateTime::parse_from_str(
        "2017-08-30 18:34:06.638997932 UTC",
        "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%.9f UTC",
    );

    println!("{:?}", dt1); // Ok(2017-08-30T18:34:06.638997932)
}
```

Comment: How can I parse a `String` instead of a `&'static str`? All examples from Chrono are always using `&'static str`. But that's not how you do it in a real program. In production you use `String` for everything.

Comment: @TheFox [What is the idiomatic way to convert a String to &str?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29026066/155423); [Idiomatic transformations for String, &str, Vec<u8> and &\[u8\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41034635/155423); [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423). TL;DR: if you have a `s: String`,  you can pass `&s` and it will become a `&str`